# Performance differences in Tensorflow when nesting multiple operations at a single node

Tags: tensorflow

I am somewhat new to Tensorflow, and was wondering what kind of performance considerations I should keep in mind when constructing a graph.

My main question is whether there is any change in the performance of a computation when multiple operations are nested at a single node, when compared to assigning each operation to a separate node.  For example, if I want to use batch normalization, followed by a dense layer, and an relu, I could structure it so that all three operations are performed at a single node:

```
input=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,input_len],dtype=tf.float32
output=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(input),W)+b)
```

or I could separate them into three separate nodes:

```
input=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,input_len],dtype=tf.float32
x1=tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(input)
x2=tf.matmul(x1,W)+b
ouput=tf.nn.relu(x2)
```

Obviously this will affect the compactness/readability of the code, but does this also affect how TF implements the graph, and runs the computations?  Is nesting operations at a single node discouraged, and if so is it because of performance issues, or just stylistic?

If it makes a difference, I am interested in running my computations on a gpu.

Comment: You can use tensorboard ( https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz ) to visualize the graph which is being constructed. In your concrete case I don't think the created graphs will actually differ. A bit less readable but you can also print out the graph definition (a protobuf representation of fhe graph) to see what tensorflow created under the hood (see: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#graphdef )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both code fragments will generate identical TensorFlow graphs, and the resulting graphs will have the same performance characteristics.

To validate this assertion, you can look at the `tf.GraphDef` protocol buffer that TensorFlow builds by calling `print tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()` after running either code fragment.